# Connect to local SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, apple-m1, azure-sql-edge

I run the following code in Python on mac M1:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'localhost' 
username = 'sa' 
password = 'password' 
database = 'Fin_Data_TST' 
db_connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=" + server + ";Database=" + database + ";UID=" + username + ";PWD=" + password + ";"
conn = pyodbc.connect(db_connection_string, autocommit=True)
```

I receive an error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: (‘HYT00’, ‘[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)’)

I run a SQL server in docker on the same mac device with image = Microsoft Artifact Registry

How can I debug this error? It seems that I don’t receive a connection request when I check the SQL logs. I ran

```
drivers = pyodbc.drivers()
for d in drivers:
    print(d)
```

To check if I have the correct drivers. I also tried different names for server variable, adding the IP address, port, changing ODBC driver to 17, … I can connect to the database with the same credentials via Azure Data Studio.

Comment: Are you running the Python code directly on the macOS host, or is it running inside a Docker container (or a Dev Container in Visual Studio Code)? If it's inside a Docker container have you tried using `SERVER=host.docker.internal;` yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm running the code on the macOS host. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Docker images for SQL Server expose their service on port 1433. When you created the Docker container did you publish it to the standard port on the host, 1433, or did you use a custom port? If, for example, you used port 2544 then you would need to include this in the connection string, e.g.: `SERVER=localhost,2544;`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried this as well. I ran the following code:

import pyodbc
server = 'localhost:1433' 
username = 'sa' 
password = 'password' 
database = 'Fin_Data_TST' 
db_connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=" + server + ";Database=" + database + ";UID=" + username + ";PWD=" + password + ";"
conn = pyodbc.connect(db_connection_string, autocommit=True)

I also did a variant were I used the docker ID instead of "localhost". I tried using "," & ":" for defining the port btw.